# Is it an acceptable practice to implement a WCF service capable of both SOAP and REST?

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

I followed directions of other users to create a service that can run both REST and SOAP.  At first glance I see no issues.  Are there any concerns about running both concurrently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue having a service that can process SOAP request and other more REST style requests.  However, the resources that you create for SOAP will be completely different than the ones you create for REST.  Also, it is rare to find a web framework that supports both styles effectively.